# c# dealing with multiple timers

Tags: c#

I have a few questions using C# with its `Timers.Timer` class.  Given the below general outline:

1 - What happens if another another `m_Timer=new Timer(...)` is called before the timer event fires?

2 - If it kills the existing timer, is there a built-in C# method of handling it and clean up or do I have to add to a `List<Timer>` then go back and purge items at some point?

3 - If adding to a list, can I remove itself from the list in `TimerHandler` ?

```
class A {
  Timer m_Timer;
  int m_JustForShow;

  public void TimerHandler(Object stateinfo) {
    // is this right?
    string id=(string) stateinfo;
    // use id to check if action has completed and if not
    // we cancel it.
    if (m_JustForShow==1) {
      // Is this running under the objects context and I can just do this?
    }
  }

  public void MyEventNotification(in MyEventInfo ei)
  {
    if (ei.State!=MyEventState.Completed) {
      m_Timer=new Timer(TimerHandler, new ei.StringID, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's very much worth noting that `System.Timers.Timer` is an `IDisposable` - which means you must explicitly dispose of it when you're done with it. So if you assign a new one then dispose of the one before it.

Microsoft's Reactive Framwork (System.Reactive) contains a number of useful classes that can help here.

`System.Reactive.Disposables.SerialDisposable` is an object that automatically disposes an object if a new assignment is made to its `Disposable` property.

```
System.Reactive.Disposables.SerialDisposable serialDisposable =
    new System.Reactive.Disposables.SerialDisposable();

serialDisposable.Disposable = new System.Timers.Timer();

serialDisposable.Disposable = new System.Timers.Timer(); //First Timer now Disposed

serialDisposable.Dispose(); //Second Timer now Disposed
```

Alternatively you could use `System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable` which works like a `List<IDisposable>`, but is disposable itself to then call `.Dispose()` on all of the items in the list.

```
System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable =
    new System.Reactive.Disposables.CompositeDisposable();
    
compositeDisposable.Add(new System.Timers.Timer());
compositeDisposable.Add(new System.Timers.Timer());
compositeDisposable.Add(new System.Timers.Timer());

compositeDisposable.Dispose(); // All three timers disposed
```

A word of caution when manipulating lists from multiple threads - you need to use locking. Using `System.Reactive.Disposables.SerialDisposable` solves that problem too.

Answer (score 0):

1. Nothing happens to an existing `System.Timers.Timer` if you create a new `System.Timers.Timer`.
2. Specifically it does not kill any existing timer.
3. With `System.Timers.Timer`, your `TimerHandler` will execute on a thread in the thread pool.  If your handler modifies any variable that may be accessed by another thread, then you'll have to give due consideration to synchronization.  This includes potential race conditions caused by removing a timer from a `List<Timer>` of timers, if that list is being accessed elsewhere.

---

###### Regarding your concern about an active timer being "deleted" when you have no references to it:

A `System.Timers.Timer` internally uses a `System.Threading.Timer` <sup>[1](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/System/services/timers/system/timers/Timer.cs#L133)</sup> which places an object into a linked list <sup>[2](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs#L499)</sup> along with other active timers, to form a queue, so the reference (to the callback method anyway) is reachable even if you don't have one yourself because the static timer queue keeps it alive <sup>[3](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/51cf7850defa8a17d815b4700b67116e3fa283c2/mscorlib/system/threading/timer.cs#L54)</sup>.  So an active timer will not be garbage collected, even if you have no references to it.

Comment: so then the m_Timer just references the new Timer object but the old one is out in limbo (it doesn't "delete" it at that time like an auto pointer in C++)?  Some point later the old one will be cleaned up.  Could it be cleaned up before the callback fires?

Comment: @user3161924 I suppose "limbo" is a fair description.  I added to my answer with details.

Comment: @user3161924 - It's not going to be cleaned up if it has a delegate attached to a variable that is in scope.